# How to pass a react component as a variable, to child component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

When I have defined a component in a variable, and I am trying to pass it to a component as a children prop, `Objects are not valid as a React child` error is shown.

What is a correct way to do this?

```
function AnotherComponent(){
  return "Another";
}

function ChildComponent(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  console.log(children);
  return (
    <Typography
      component="div"
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`full-width-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`full-width-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      <Box p={3}>{children}</Box>
    </Typography>
  );
}

function MainComponent(){
  const tabItems = [
    { "component": AnotherComponent}
  ];

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      {tabItems.map((tabItem,index) => (
        <ChildComponent value={value} index={tabItem.index}>
          {tabItem.component}
        </ChildComponent>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tabItem.component` is just an object. This should work :

```
{tabItems.map((tabItem, index) => {
    const TheComponent = tabItem.component;
    return (
      <TabPanel value={value} index={tabItem.index}>
        <TheComponent />
      </TabPanel>
    );
  })}
```

Comment: Or without changing his code: `{ "component":AnotherComponent}` becomes     `{ "component": <AnotherComponent />}` because the whole point of his loop is to be able to pass that "tabItem"

Comment: This does not seem to work -- 


While this code does not render `AnotherComponent`, though the error is not visible.
`
{tabItems.map((tabItem,index) => {
                    let TabComponent = tabItem.component;
                    return <TabPanel value={value} index={tabItem.index} dir={theme.direction}>
                        <TabComponent/>
                    </TabPanel>
                })}
`

Comment: What is `TabPanel` ? The problem might be there

Comment: Hmm, `TabPanel` should be `ChildComponent`, corrected the code

Comment: It shows something like this - 
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props: {}
ref: null
type: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref), displayName: "WithSnackbar(WithStyles(Clip))", options: {…}, render: ƒ, Naked: ƒ, …}
....

Comment: You should provide the complete source code. Otherwise we can't help you

Comment: Removing ` hidden={value !== index}` from `ChildComponent` works fine

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way you initialise the array is really just assigning a function into it. Exactly as error says - you cant render a function. You have to wrap that function into JSX syntax to do the whole `React.createChild` thingy.

So just change this line

```
 const tabItems = [
{ "component": AnotherComponent}
];
```

to this:

```
 const tabItems = [
{ "component": <AnotherComponent />}
];
```

and it will work like a charm. :)